# Saving a Card and Creating Customer at Stripe using Android Custom Form

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I have a Card Form in my Kotlin based Android Mobile app(attached image) of mine which I made using this package

[brain tree Card Form](https://github.com/braintree/android-card-form)

after all the success validation I am willing to create a card and customer from mobile using

> **Stripe SDK For ANDROID**

**NOTE:**
As I am not using the Stripe SDK provided CARD INPUT WIDGET so cannot use those functions to do so.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED SO FAR:**

Been into the sources provided by the Stripe Team
URL here https://stripe.com/docs/payments/integration-builder
and coding examples from https://github.com/stripe-samples
but I am unable to find a solution.

Been thinking to create a Card element and then create a customer session and save detail and take the data out of the ACTIVITY RESULT function later on.

but any help would be great in this regard if possible, please.

here is a sample form

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error or are you just asking how to use the Stripe Android SDK?

Comment: using the cardInPutWidget sending card and creating a customer is easy! but! I want to send the card from my custom form and send do what I stated above on stripe! @PaulAsjes